# Is there a way to expand a regex scope to include characters to the previous/next space?

Tags: regex

Say I have the text `test test words to match test text`, I would like to expand a regex that would normally create a partial match (say, `(rds\sto\smatc)`) to include characters up to the next/previous space and return the text `words to match`. Is there a way to modify the regex to lookbehind and lookahead to the next space character and include the characters in between in a match?

Comment: This is unclear. What do you have so far?

Comment: I think you ask for `\S*rds\sto\smatc\S*`

Comment: Using lookarounds would achieve that there have to be those additional letters, but NOT that they are caught be the match. I think that is almost the opposite of what you want. Instead extend the regex inside the `()` to include the desired letters. You are aware of wildcard-like syntaxes like `\w+` or `[[:alpha:]]{1,}`, aren't you? If you are not aware of those, then you have missed most of the power of regex and should urgently find and follow some tutorials.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works exactly how I was hoping, thanks!. What I had so far with the match before was just `rds to match`.

Comment: `to include characters up to the next/previous space and return the text words to match` Regex does not know what a **_`word`_** is. That is a concept reserved for language processors. This construct `\S` matches 1,114,082 Unicode characters. Compare that to 26 letters in the English alpabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may append `\S*` matching *any 0 or more chars other than whitespace* on both sides of your expression and use

```
\S*rds\s+to\s+matc\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOX214/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5CS*rds%5Cs%2Bto%5Cs%2Bmatc%5CS*):

[image]